Converting from actual distance to pixel distance in zenith aerial drone image
I have a set of zenith pictures taken by a flying drone.
There are some points of interest in the image for which I know the distance from the center of the image in meters. For each one of those points, I want to draw a circle on the picture which has as center the center of the image, and as radius the distance between the center and that point.
In order to be able to do this, I need to figure out how to convert the distance in meters to a distance in pixels.
This is the algorithm that I have been using:
First, I compute the ground sampling distance (GSD) as
$$\frac{\mathrm{altitudeInMeters} \cdot \mathrm{sensorWidthInMeters}}{\mathrm{focalLengthInMeters}\cdot \mathrm{imageWidthInPixels}}$$
Then I divide the distance in meters by that amount: $\frac{\mathrm{distanceInMeters}}{\mathrm{GSD}}$.
Given that the image is rendered inside of an interactive web application that allows for zooming (which is effectively done by making the image larger by some scale factor), I also multiply the resulting amount by the scale factor.
In theory, this should work, but it's consistently yielding circles that are visually way too small compared to their expected size.
Is there anything wrong with this approach? Is there a better way?

This seems reasonable to me.  I think my next step would be to try to determine the error factor and see if it is consistent.  If so, you might just have the wrong focal length or a unit error.

Also I would work through one example by hand to see if the calculation comes out as you expect.  That has been a good way for me to check if there is a bug.
